# Glassfish - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket, glassfish-3, java-7

I was following this [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/websockets_and_java_ee_7) to run a sample websocket application in glasshfish. The deployment failed with the following error. But the mentioned class file is available in the pom.xml and it is listed in the dependencies as well. Could you please help?

[image]

```
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/websocket/spi/Endpoint. Please see server.log for more details.
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:130)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:212)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

Comment: it would help if you can also post some/part of your code what you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved. You should not have the same jar in modules folder of glassfish and WEB-INF\lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to clean and build your project.